# Why are key/value pairs reversed when creating dictionary directly from user input

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, input

Working on creating a basic student/grade dictionary.  I have a working solution that reads the input on one line and then stores the key/value pair in the dictionary.  Code reads as:

```
student_scores = {}
for _ in range(int(input())):
    key, value = input(), input()
    student_scores[key] = value
    print(student_scores)
```

Example input for the code is:

```
2
John 
50
Mary
47
```

This works fine and gives the expected (to me) output:

```
{'John ': '50'}
{'John ': '50', 'Mary': '47'}
```

However, when I try to condense the input to work directly into the dictionary...

```
student_scores = {}
for _ in range(int(input())):
    student_scores[input()] = input()
    print(student_scores)
```

for the exact same input as above the key/value pairs are reversed and the output put is:

```
{'50': 'John '}
{'47': 'Mary', '50': 'John '}
```

The question, then is why is Python reversing the order of the input and what is the proper formatting to read this in on a single line of code?  While I have a working solution, I feel there's something fundamental that I'm not understanding with either input() or the construction of dictionaries.  Sorry for the basic question, have only been working on Python for about a month now.

Comment: Unlike, say, Java, Python fully evaluates the right-hand side of an assignment before evaluating any expressions on the left, so the right-hand `input()` evaluates first. There's probably a good dupe around here somewhere.

Comment: (I wish Python would evaluate LHS expressions first, but that's not the design decision they made.)

Comment: Couldn't find anything good for expression evaluation order. Everything close was talking about evaluating the RHS before performing assignments in a multiple assignment, or performing one assignment before evaluating expressions in the next assignment target, rather than evaluating the RHS before evaluating expressions in the assignment targets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike, say, Java, Python fully evaluates the right-hand side of an assignment before evaluating any expressions on the left. That means that in

```
student_scores[input()] = input()
```

the evaluation order goes

```
                          input()
student_scores
               input()
```

and then the assignment. Thus, the `input()` on the right is evaluated first, unlike in

```
key, value = input(), input()
```

where the `input()` on the left evaluates first, and the order in which the `input()` calls read input is reversed.

---

There isn't really a good one-liner for this. Sticking it on two lines should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  Fully explains what I was not understanding about assignment using input().  Much appreciated.